# Data being undefined while I have already defined it?

Tags: javascript, undefined, discord.js

Alright, So I am using the discord economy npm [Discord-Economy Npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-economy)
and I have defined balance but when I try output it nothing happens. I have tried to add a "Support aka work" Thing and still nothing, heres the code I have so far

```
if (msg.content === prefix + "bal") {
 const output = eco.FetchBalance(msg.author.id)
 msg.channel.send(`${output.balance}`) 

 if (msg.content === prefix + "support") {
const output = eco.FetchBalance(msg.author.id)
msg.channel.send(`${output.balance}`)
}
```

Comment: what is undefined exactly ?

Comment: The balance of the user, Since it fetches the balance then outputs it, But it outputs it as undefined yet Ive done this
`const balance = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs, `FetchBalance` is a promise and its fields are `userid` and `balance`.
You'd have to await the promise first so you can actually get the data being returned, as follows:

```
if (msg.content === prefix + "bal") {
 const output = await eco.FetchBalance(msg.author.id) // Adding await to fulfil the promise
 msg.channel.send(`${output.balance}`) 

 if (msg.content === prefix + "support") {
const output = await eco.FetchBalance(msg.author.id)
msg.channel.send(`${output.balance}`)
}
```

p.s. you won't need to declare `const balance = 0`